# Got error: Cannot create an instance of View Model

Tags: android

In Main Activity, i tried to get an instance of my viewModel and observe a field:

```
 mRep = DataRepository.getInstance(this);     

    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, new TeaViewModelFactory(mRep)).get(TeaViewModel.class);

    mViewModel.getTea().observe(this, new Observer<Tea>(){
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final Tea tea){

           // mTeaName.setText(tea.getName());

        }
    });
```

First i got the error Mesage:

```
 NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
```

I thought there is a problem with the observed data, so i commented out:

```
mViewModel.getTea().observe(this, new Observer<Tea>(){
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final Tea tea){

            // mTeaName.setText(tea.getName());

        }
    });
```

and wanted to log the observed field in my ViewModel:

Instead of the data, now i got this :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{....}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class TeaViewModel
```

So something with the instantiation of my ViewModel must have gone wrong...

The whole TeaViewModelClass:

```
public class TeaViewModel extends ViewModel {

private final DataRepository mRepository;
private final LiveData<Tea> mTea;
private final MutableLiveData<TeaDetailModel> mTeaDetail = new MutableLiveData<>();

public TeaViewModel(DataRepository repository) {
    mRepository = repository;
    mTea = mRepository.getRecentTea();
    Log.v("Tea:", mTea.toString());
    //Log.v("Tea:", "Here");
}

public LiveData<Tea> getTea() {
    return mTea;
}

public void setTeaImage(String teaType) {
    mTeaDetail.setValue(new TeaDetailModel(teaType));
}

public LiveData<TeaDetailModel> getTeaImage() {
    return mTeaDetail;
}

public void setFavorite() {
    mRepository.updateFavorite(Objects.requireNonNull(mTea.getValue()).getName());
}
```

TeaModelFactory:

```
public class TeaViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

public final DataRepository mRepository;

public static TeaViewModelFactory createFactory(Activity activity) {
    Context context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    if (context == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Not yet attached to Application");
    }

    return new TeaViewModelFactory(DataRepository.getInstance(context));
}

public TeaViewModelFactory(DataRepository repository) {
    mRepository = repository;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
    try {
        return modelClass.getConstructor(DataRepository.class)
                .newInstance(mRepository);
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException |
            NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot create an instance of " + modelClass, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this line is causing issue return new TeaViewModelFactory(DataRepository.getInstance(context)); Just debug what is returned at this line?

Comment: Also, can't you pass "mRepository" instead "DataRepository.getInstance(context)" to your "return new TeaViewModelFactory(...);"

Comment: did you solve the error?